# Python - Find the average for each column in a csv file excluding headers and time

Tags: python, csv

I am reading in a csv file like so:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data_list = list(reader)
```

Here `data_list` is a list of each line in the csv file. So `data_list[0]` is the first line in the csv file (i.e the Headers), `data_list[1]` onwards is the actual lines containing data in csv file and `data_line[1:][1]` is the time.

So basically

```
data_list=
[['','Header1','Header2','Header3'],
['12:02:11', '2.3', '6.2', '11.8'],
['12:05:25', '1.5', '7.5', '13.2'],
['12:10:48', '4.1', '6.8', '12.6'],
['12:13:17', '1.6', '7.1', '12.1']]
```

I want to find the average of each column but excluding the Headers and the time as part of the calculations but keeping the Headers for the output and only taking one decimal place. Overall I want to produce something like this:

```
average_data_list=
[['','Header1','Header2','Header3'],
['', 2.3', '6.9', '12.4']]
```

I have been using [Python - Calculate average for every column in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597477/python-calculate-average-for-every-column-in-a-csv-file) as a guide but my code keeps throwing errors as I can't get it to skip the headers and time correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    data_list = list(reader)
    rows = [''] + ['{:.1f}'.format(sum(float(x) for x in y) / len(data_list)) for y in zip(*data_list)[1:]]
    average_data_list = [header] + [rows]

    print average_data_list
```

This would display:

```
[['', 'Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'], ['', '2.4', '6.9', '12.4']]
```

The trick here is to read the header row first so that it does not get in the way. The `zip(*data_list)` is used to convert your list of rows to a list of columns so that the average can be easily calculated.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the average only one decimal place long? like incorporate `%.1f` somewhere correctly?

Comment: Indeed, just replace the `str` with a suitable `format`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data_list):
    if i == 0:
         continue

    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        average_data_list[j] += value

quantity = len(data_list) - 1
for i, sum in enumerate(average_data_list):
    average_data_list[i] = sum / quantity
```

First you first sum all the values into the array; Second you iterate over the resulting array computing its average.

Another option would be to create an array of the quantities and increment at each step, in the case you want to ignore **nulls**.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  a,b and c aggregate the sums from each respective column.  Then just divided by the number of rows minus one (ignoring the header row) and print only a single decimal.

```
a,b,c = 0,0,0
for i, row in enumerate(data_list):
    if i != 0:
        a += float(row[1])
        b += float(row[2])
        c += float(row[3])

num_vals = len(data_list) - 1 #because of the header
a /= num_vals
b /= num_vals
c /= num_vals
print "{0:.1f} , {1:.1f}, {2:.1f}".format(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fairly easy to solve using the `csv` and `statistics` modules provided in Python's standard library. The following example loads the data from the CSV file using the `DictReader` class while simultaneously pivoting the data using the column names. Averaging the data in the columns is accomplished with the `mean` function while data conversion is handled via `map` and `float`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import statistics


def main():
    with open('data.csv', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        column = {key: [] for key in reader.fieldnames}
        for row in reader:
            for key in reader.fieldnames:
                column[key].append(row[key])
    print('Header1 Average =', statistics.mean(map(float, column['Header1'])))
    print('Header2 Average =', statistics.mean(map(float, column['Header2'])))
    print('Header3 Average =', statistics.mean(map(float, column['Header3'])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```