# Troubles averaging all the grades from a "CSV" file

Tags: python, csv, split

So I am new to python and I am having a hard time figuring this code. I am trying to use "CSV File" called exam_grades.csv and then write a function that reads in all my values in the file but using the string class split() method to split this long string into a list of strings. Each string represents a grade. Then my function should return the average of all the grades.

So far this is what I have; I can open the .csv file just fine but I'm having troubles averaging all the grades. I have some commented out because I am sure where to go from what I have been doing :(

```
def fileSearch():
    'Problem 4'
    readfile = open('exam_grades.csv', "r")
    for line in readfile:
        l = line.split(str(","))
        #num_grades = len(l)
        #averageAllGrades = l * 500 
        #return num_grades
        print(l)
fileSearch()
```

Any advice? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should **really** be looking for/using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). And the [with](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers) context manager. But you've got a good start here. Your problem is most likely that you're not doing `for grade in l:` to iterate over each individual grade on a line - then doing `grade = int(grade)` to convert it into a integer *(so you can do maths)*. And then doing `sum_total = sum_total + grade` and finally, do `average = sum_total / len(l)`. That should give you enough info to finish up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Calculate average for every column in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597477/python-calculate-average-for-every-column-in-a-csv-file) (It's probably not a exact match to your problem, but it never will be. Take inspiration from this (and other) posts. Mangle what you can learn from them into what fits you).

Comment: This isn't necessary for your problem but just as an aside as a nice builtin function which is neat for your problem is the `sum` function which takes an iterable such as a list and sums all the values inside it.

Comment: And a little bit of good practice which is especially good if you make a longer code reading from a file is to always call `readfile.close()` after you have finished reading the file so that it isn't left open

Answer (score 0):

Most CSV files have a header at the top, you'll want to skip that but for simplicity sake, let's say we ignore that.

Here's some code that works:

```py
def fileSearch():
    'Problem 4'
    readfile = open('exam_grades.csv', "r")
    grade_sum = 0
    grade_count = 0
    for line in readfile:
        l = line.split(str(","))
        for grade in l:
            grade_sum += int(grade)
            grade_count += 1
    print(grade_sum/grade_count)

fileSearch()
```

This assumes you have multiple lines with grades and multiple grades per line.

We're keeping track of two variables here, the sum of all grades and the number of all grades we've added to the list (we're also casting to integers, since you're going to be reading strings).

When you add all the grades up and divide by the number of grades, you get an average.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @rwandan See [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)