# Python program to average columns and change value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python programming but did not see any SO solutions that accomplished this.

I am trying to write a Python program that opens a CSV, averages all of the values in a column, and stores that columns average value. Then, if a value is above that average, change the value to 1, if its below, change to 0. Below is a description of what I mean:

```
| 2  | 5  | 11 | 2  |
| 0  | 7  | 8  | 11 |
| 22 | 55 | 4  | 3  |
| 0  | 2  | 8  | 7  |
```

Would have averages like: `Col[0] = 6, Col[1] = 17, Col[2] = 8, Col[3] = 6` 
Then, the table would change to:

```
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
```

I am not asking for a code writing service, but I am very new to this. I think the pseudocode would look something like:

```
average_columns(csv myFile){
    for each column in csv:
        average = sum(column) / len(column)
        for each row in column:
            if row.value >= average{
                row.value = 1
            }else{
                row_value = 0
            }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this approach?

Thank you

Comment: Does it have to be pure Python or can you use the Pandas library?

Comment: I can use the pandas library. I have never used it before, but am trying to read about "dataframes" which might be useful I think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597477/python-calculate-average-for-every-column-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Hi @Primusa, I was unable to use that question to satisfy what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure Python (i.e. not using a library like pandas), the implementation would probably loop over the entire table twice. Depending on the size of the data set, you could load it in its entirety and then process the result twice, or you could process it line by line twice. Since I don't know the size, the latter approach seems the safest:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf:
    # setting the quoting causes the reader to interpret non-quoted values as floats
    cr = csv.reader(inf, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    # initialise sums to the first line, assumes there's at least one line
    sums = next(cr)
    n = 0
    # add all the other lines, one by one
    for row in cr:
        n += 1
        sums = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums, row)]
    # calculate averages from the sums
    averages = [x / n for x in sums]

# second loop over the input, writing the result to output
with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf:
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf:
        cr = csv.reader(inf, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        cw = csv.writer(outf)
        for row in cr:
            cw.writerow([1 if x > a else 0 for x, a in zip(row, averages)])
```

Example `input.csv`:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4
1,6,'blah',8
1,1,1,1
```

Resulting `output.csv`:

```
0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1
0,0,0,0
```

If your data does contain non-float values, you need to deal with these and one way would be to assign them value 0, like this:

```
import csv


def safe_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


with open('data.csv', 'r') as inf:
    cr = csv.reader(inf)
    sums = [safe_float(x) for x in next(cr)]
    n = 0
    for row in cr:
        float_row = [safe_float(x) for x in row]
        sums = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums, float_row)]
        n += 1
    averages = [x / n for x in sums]

with open('data.csv', 'r') as inf:
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf:
        cr = csv.reader(inf)
        cw = csv.writer(outf)
        for row in cr:
            float_row = [safe_float(x) for x in row]
            cw.writerow([1 if x > a else 0 for x, a in zip(float_row, averages)])
```

If you don't like sums getting overwritten on each iteration, you can replace this:

```
sums = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums, float_row)]
```

With:

```
for i in range(len(sums)):
    sums[i] += float_row[i]
```

And then of course, you can avoid calculating the length by setting it once, outside the loop. More optimisation is always possible, it really depends on your needs whether you want the code to be straightforward or run optimally.

Comment: Hi Grismar. I believe this will work, however I just realized my data is not "clean". Is there anyway for me to handle any non-numeric values as 0? I can maybe add an if statement, but I am not sure where?

Comment: Yes, instead of relying on csv.reader to do the conversion, you could just do an explicit conversion, I'll add a rewrite of the example that does this.

Comment: @roganjosh, it makes sense - you're right that it overwrites it, an alternative would be to loop over row and add them to the existing content of sums; it really depends on what you're optimising.

Comment: Hm, I am having trouble with this. <br />
`line 14 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`

Comment: @roganjosh, look again, it is used on each iteration in the zip, so it is similar to `x = x + 1`, overwriting `x` with a value based on the previous value of `x`

Comment: @JerryM. I think you grabbed an old version - the exact code above runs without issue for me and line 14 does not have a concatenation operation. Please try to run the code as provided on a simple csv before making changes.

Comment: @Grismar maybe I was, sorry. When I run it, output.csv has ALL records as 0.

Comment: @roganjosh we are looking at `sums = [x + y for x, y in zip(sums, float_row)]` yes? So it zips current `sums` with the current row, then proceeds to add up all the values of all the tuples and returns the result. I.e. with `sums` equal to `[x, y, ..., z]` going in, for `float_row` `[1, 2, ..., 4]` it will result in `sums` being `[x+1, y+2, ..., z+4]`. What am I missing here? Did you run the code?

Comment: @JerryM. I've added my example data for good measure and just reran the current examples, they both function as expected (of course I need to replace `'blah'` with a 0 to make the first one work).

Comment: @Grismar something is off...my output.csv, again, had all 0s. I have a manually made copy with 0s and 1s I did to check code, so something unfortunately is askew.

Comment: @roganjosh, you clearly are not running the code, as you are wrong - please look a 4th time at the code. It zips sums with the current row (i.e. creating a copy of sums, zipped with the values of the row) and then proceeds to build a new list of the increased sums, assigning the result to sums. The contents are not list, sums contains valid sums at the end.

Comment: @roganjosh a similar example, minimal https://pastebin.com/nHcLH6rc - no worries, happens to the best :)

Comment: @JerryM. I've copied the data from above into a new `input.csv`. I then copied my code from above into a new `script.py` and ran it in vanilla Python 3.7. The results are correct, I'm afraid you are either doing something different or have something weird in your environment.

Comment: Hi @Grismar. I can give you my data somehow if you'd like to verify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188084/discussion-between-grismar-and-jerry-m).

Comment: We found the error - the script was using `len(sums)` but should be using the length of the file, which is now collected in `n`

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
means = csv.mean(axis=0)
output = (csv > means).astype(int)

print(output)
```

Comment: Hi @anlew. Despite being the smallest code contribution, yours seems to work. Any thoughts on how to get output to be a csv file?

Comment: Sure, there is also a corresponding '.to_csv' method. For more information please take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html (there are examples at the bottom).