# Plotting data from large file in Python

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a large file (2 GB). I want to plot the data in it in `scatterplot`. The data has following format in the file.

```
day block1  block2  block3  .....
1   34.89   88.90   67.89   .....
2   77.890  33.56   76.98   .....
3   67.12   67.89   55.89   .....
... .....   .....   .....   .....
```

**pltData** will be the list of average of the column that is

```
pltData = [avg_block1, avg_block2, avg_block3, .....]
```

**pltX** and **pltY** are finite lists. For plotting the data from list named as **pltData**, I'm using following code:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

FIGURE = plt.Figure()
SUBPLOT1 = FIGURE.add_subplot(121)
SUBPLOT1.set_xlabel('x distance')
SUBPLOT1.set_ylabel('y distance')
data1 = {'x-distance' : pltX , 'y_distance' : pltY}
df3 = DataFrame(data1, columns=['x-distance','y_distance'])
plot1= SUBPLOT1.scatter(df3['x-distance'],df3['y_distance'], marker='o', s=15, linewidths=0.1, c=pltData, cmap='rainbow', vmin=min(pltData), vmax=max(pltData))
FIGURE.colorbar(plot1, ax=SUBPLOT1)
```

However, for file as large as 2GB, creating list **pltData** is impossible because number of rows and columns are large. Can someone guide me to the way I can plot the data?

Comment: There is no variable called `pltData` in your code.

Comment: Have you try using pandas package to load your data and calculate the average for the columns to get your pltData?

Comment: How many columns in the csv file?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create the list named pltData from the file. I've edited the question and put the file format for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Calculate average for every column in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597477/python-calculate-average-for-every-column-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: No. Because my file is not necessarily csv. It is a txt file and there are number of columns and rows. I dont know how many col and rows are there to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas package to load your data then from there do a mean to get average for your columns.  Something like this,

```
import pandas as pd

pltData = pd.read_csv('my2gbdata.csv')  
pltData = pltData.mean()
```

This will gives you the average for each column, from there you can use it however you need to.